# Data from a listview to a PDF

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to generate a PDF with all the data in a listview. I am using a custom listview that contains the columns: id, estudante, hora.
I can only write the estudante column data to the PDF, but I can't return the id column and the hora column.
I would like to list it in an organized manner, but I am only getting it on a single line.

```
Class listing the records:
public class ListarAlunosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lista;
public AlunoDAO dao;
public List<Aluno> alunos;
public List<Aluno>alunosFiltrados = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_listar_alunos);

        lista = findViewById(R.id.listv);
        dao = new AlunoDAO(this);
        alunos = dao.obterTodos();
        alunosFiltrados.addAll(alunos);
        //ArrayAdapter<Aluno> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<Aluno>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, alunos);
        AlunoAdapter adaptador = new AlunoAdapter(alunos, this);
        lista.setAdapter(adaptador);

    }
}

PDF generator class:

public class PDFActivity extends ListarAlunosActivity{

    Button btnCreate;
    EditText editText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layoutactivity_pdf);

        btnCreate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.create);
        editText =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                createPdf(editText.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
    private void createPdf(String sometext){
        // create a new document
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        // crate a page description
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(300, 600, 1).create();
        // start a page
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        AlunoAdapter adaptador = new AlunoAdapter(alunos, this);
        lista.setAdapter(adaptador);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawText(sometext, 80, 50, paint);
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(alunos), 10, 20, paint);
        //canvas.drawText(alunos.toString(), 10, 16, paint);
        //canvas.drawt
        // finish the page
        document.finishPage(page);

        // Create Page 2
        pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(300, 600, 2).create();
        page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        canvas = page.getCanvas();
        paint = new Paint();
        //paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        //canvas.drawCircle(100, 100, 100, paint);
        document.finishPage(page);
        // write the document content
        String directory_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/";
        File file = new File(directory_path);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        String targetPdf = directory_path+"teste495.pdf";
        File filePath = new File(targetPdf);
        try {
            document.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Salvo com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("main", "error "+e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Não possível salvar: " + e.toString(),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // close the document
        document.close();
    }
}

class AlunoAdapter:

public class AlunoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private List<Aluno> alunos;
   private Activity atividade;

    public AlunoAdapter(List<Aluno> alunos, Activity atividade){
       this.alunos = alunos;
       this.atividade = atividade;
   }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return alunos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return alunos.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return alunos.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = atividade.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        TextView id = v.findViewById(R.id.tvId);
        TextView estudante = v.findViewById(R.id.tvEstudante);
        TextView hora = v.findViewById(R.id.tvHora);

        Aluno a = alunos.get(position);
        id.setText(String.valueOf(alunos.get(position).getId()));
        estudante.setText(a.getEstudante());
        hora.setText(a.getHora());
        return v;
    }
}
I hope the PDF will be generated with all existing Listview data.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the object Aluno? You could try changing your toString() method in it.

It looks you are printing data on the pdf using "String.valueOf(alunos)", which is why you get only one single line.

You could replace

```
canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(alunos), 10, 20, paint);
```

with

```
for (Aluno a : alunos)
{
   canvas.drawText(a.getId() + "\t" + a.getEstudante() + "\t" + a.getHora()), 10, 20, paint);     
}
```

Now I think this may print all Aluno objects on the same line, so you may want to try something like

```
int x = 20;
for (Aluno a : alunos)
{
   canvas.drawText(a.getId() + "\t" + a.getEstudante() + "\t" + a.getHora()), 10, x, paint);
   x+=20;     
}
```

I hope it helps.